# Legend label is not adding for multiple plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I wanted to read 5 `csv` files. I have the following function which plots the graphs separately and I wanted to add a legend to to each plot. However, I am getting this warning the legend is not being added to the plots even if i have a label added to my function.

`UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('test3.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('test4.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv('test5.csv')


def runplot(df, title, label):   
    rows, cols = df.shape

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(df['price'].values, df['cost'].values)
    ax.legend()


    plt.title(title)
    plt.annotate('test!', 
                 xy=(rows, df.ix[rows-1,'cost']),  
                 xycoords='data',
                 xytext=(-30,30),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))


runplot(df1, 'test1.csv', label='test1')
runplot(df2, 'test2.csv', label='test2')
runplot(df3, 'test3.csv', label='test3')
runplot(df4, 'test4.csv', label='test4')
runplot(df5, 'test5.csv', label='test5')
```

How can we make the legend show in the plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `lebel` argument when plot and use `handle` to make a legend. Try to write like this:

```
def runplot(df, title, label):   
    rows, cols = df.shape

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line1, = ax.plot(df['price'].values, df['cost'].values, label=label)
    ax.legend(handles=[line1])

    plt.title(title)
    plt.annotate('test!', 
                 xy=(rows, df.ix[rows-1,'cost']),  
                 xycoords='data',
                 xytext=(-30,30),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```